# Rails + Using Friendly ID for slug generation and creating trouble while accessing from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, slug

Facing some strange problem with respect to Slug in Rails

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
2.1.2 :001 > Tutorial.last
  Tutorial Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "tutorials".* FROM "tutorials" 
  ORDER BY "tutorials"."id" DESC LIMIT 1

 => #<Tutorial id: 3, title: "Populating the Database’s with seeds.rb",
    state: "Publish", content_introduction: "<p>Demo Data</p>\r\n", 
    slug: "populating-the-database-s-with-seeds-rb"> 

2.1.2 :002 > Tutorial.last.slug
  Tutorial Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "tutorials".* FROM "tutorials" 
    ORDER BY "tutorials"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => "populating-the-database’s-with-seeds.rb"
```

In database it show "-" by replacing special character but while accessing it gives as it.

**Model**

```
def slug
  title.strip.downcase.gsub(/[:,'"%^&*+=<>.`~]/,"").gsub("’","").gsub("  ", " ").gsub(" ", "-")
end

def to_param
  "#{slug}".parameterize
end

extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: [ :slugged, :history ]
```

So while accessing the page using slug it gives error. Please have a look and suggest something.

Comment: Paste link code where you are facing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between what you see the value of slug in `Tutorial.last` and what you get in `Tutorial.last.slug`

`Tutorial.last` fetches the last record from the table which is giving you the `slug` saved in the database, but `Tutorial.last.slug` is calling the `slug` method defined in your model, `Tutorial.last` is an object and using that object you are calling the `slug` method

```
def slug
  title.strip.downcase.gsub(/[:,'"%^&*+=<>.`~]/,"").gsub("’","").gsub("  ", " ").gsub(" ", "-")
end
```

So comment out the above method and you will get the same results in both cases!

Looks like the `slug` method which you have defined in your model is manipulating the `title` field to get the slug value, but as far as I know `friendly_id` gem itself handles it, so just comment out the slug method. It will solve your problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: Agree. Tutorial.last.slug is calling the slug method present in model. Nice Catch .. Thanks